ElasticSearch Regex Logic Problems
I am running into some ElasticSearch woes I can't seem to get past, specifically with the regex query type. I have an index named test-index. Inside of it are documents with a url field. One particular document has it's url field set to the following:
https://hello-world.com/help/me
I want to be able to run a query that will return it in my result set using a regular expression. Here is my query:
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "url": "*.hello-world.com/help/me/?"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Basically, I want any url that matches the sub-domain, second-level domain, top-level domain, and subdirectory (with or without final /) to match. However, when I run the above query, the expected document is not returned in the result set. Based on things I've learned about ElasticSearch regexes, I also tried the following query updates but to no avail:
*.hello-world\.com\/help\/me\/?
*.hello-world\\.com\\/help\\/me\\/?
*.hello-world\\.com/help/me/?
(https?:\\/\\/)?(www\\.)?hello-world\\.com\\/help\\/me\\/?
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?hello-world\.com\/help\/me\/?

I don't really understand why this document isn't catching. I have run an exact match query against the index and the document is caught that way. Is there something I am not understanding about regex queries in ElasticSearch? Is there another path I could possibly take with this? Thanks again in advance!

Just swap * and . to get .*

Solution without Regexp and Wildcard
The fastest solution is a solution without regexps and wildcards
URL isn't atomic data. So it should be splitted into parts
Mapping with every part of the URL as a field of the parsed_url object
PUT /test-index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "url": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "parsed_url": {
                "properties": {
                    "scheme": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "domain": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "query": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "fragment": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "extension": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "original": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

All fields are keyword
We use the uri_parts ingest processor
PUT _ingest/pipeline/url_parser
{
    "description" : "Parse an URL in the url field into the parsed_url field",
    "processors" : [
        {
            "uri_parts": {
                "field": "url",
                "target_field": "parsed_url"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Documents
PUT /test-index/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"url":"https://sub.hello-world.com/help/me/index.php?param=value#label"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"url":"https://hello-world.com/help/me"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"url":""}

Document with "_id":3 has no a correct URL
URLs are parsed by update_by_query with the prepared pipeline
POST /test-index/_update_by_query?pipeline=url_parser

It's time to search. Every part could be found by the separate term query.
GET /test-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "parsed_url.domain": "hello-world.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "parsed_url.path": "/help/me"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "test-index",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 1.5686159,
                "_source" : {
                    "parsed_url" : {
                        "path" : "/help/me",
                        "original" : "https://hello-world.com/help/me",
                        "scheme" : "https",
                        "domain" : "hello-world.com"
                    },
                    "url" : "https://hello-world.com/help/me"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Possible improvements are to extract a subdomain, a domain, and a domain zone with another update_by_query

Regexp
GET test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "url":"https?://(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?hello-world.com\/help/me/?"
    }
  }
}

Wildcard
GET test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url": "*hello-world.com/help/me*"
    }
  }
}

Quick Tip
Both could be slow because this can increase the iterations needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.
Try to use UAX URL email tokenizer to perform search on URLs.

Dear @Ashish Tiwari, could you please provide an example with using UAX URL email tokenizer for searching of an URL
